# Grape API and Ruby on Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, grape-api

I started off with a standard Ruby on Rails (version 4) project which I then added the Grape Gem to build an API. The RoR part acts as a web-based administration front to the API.

My config.ru files looks like this:

```
run Rails.application
run MyAPI::API
```

This works fine locally when using the brick web server, but when I push to Heroku only the first in the list works. I'm guessing this is because Heroku only allows one process, whereas locally I can have as many as I like. What are the ways in which I could have both the RoR app and the API working together?

Hope I have included enough information. Many thanks,
David.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the webserver you are using at heroku does not evaluate your config.ru.
You can include your API within Rails via routes.rb. Add an entry like

```
mount MyAPI::API => '/'
```

Also you have to ensure that inside the application.rb your app is loaded like this:

```
config.paths.add File.join('app', 'api'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]
```